# 2 Tap events at the same time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, tap

If we have 2 divs, is it possible to tap with different fingers on these divs and call one function? When tapping at different time on the divs the function is called, at the same time nothing happens. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: yes its possible, check out this project http://quojs.tapquo.com/ as an example.

Comment: Hi , thank you very much for your response. I created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/uthm1ao6/ .
I use tapquo . If i tap on a div it disappears. I want to tap at the same time with different fingers on the 2 divs and simultaneously hide for example. Is that possible?
Thank you very much for your time